# Why does dereferencing behave differently with malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

In the examples below, dereferencing at the time of assigning value does not show any error with malloc, How come?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *p;
    printf("%d", &p);
    int a = 10;
    *p = a;
    printf("%d", *p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

[without malloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHzZ4.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%d", &p);
    int a = 10;
    *p = a;
    printf("%d", *p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

[with malloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovoyg.png)

Comment: please help i am really getting confused in pointers

Comment: Please format code by leading the line with 4 spaces. Also take great care to format the code correctly so that it's easy to follow. I made a pass at this in my edits but you might double check to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Please dont shout in the title

Comment: Perhaps you should read `man malloc`. You are not supposed to free data that haven't  been allocated by a member of `malloc` family of functions (example 1). You're not supposed to cast results of `malloc` in C (example 2).

Comment: In the first program, what does `p` point to? Local variables are not initialized, their values are *indeterminate* and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thank you for amending the question. It's credible now. UV'd

Comment: why should one not cast a result returned by malloc ?

Answer (score 4):

In the first example, `p` is uninitialized.  Dereferencing its value with `*p` invokes undefined behavior.

In the second example, `p` is assigned a pointer returned by `malloc()`.  Either `p` is `NULL` and dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior or `p` holds a valid address for a block of memory large enough to store an `int` and properly aligned for any type. Thus dereferencing `p` to store the value of `a` is defined, and the second `printf` will print `10`.

What the first `printf` prints in both cases is undefined.  The address `&p` is not a proper type for format `%d`, behavior is undefined.

You could fix this code by changing it to `printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);` but it would print the address of local variable `p`.

You probably intend to write `printf("%p\n", (void*)p);` which would print the actual address contained in `p`, but this would also invoke undefined behavior in the first case because `p` is uninitialized and could contain a trap representation.

Comment: Regarding how to print pointer values: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/3750/formatted-input-output/12982/printing-the-value-of-a-pointer-to-an-object#t=201607311741210873583

Comment: @harry: if this answer is useful, you can accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score.